# Как вывести только знаки после точки C?

Tags: c

Мне надо вывести знаки после точки, к примеру, с **2.6569** я должен вывести: **6569**.
Язык C.

Comment: После запятой - это значит, что у вас строка? Потому что в числах вообще-то точки...

Comment: Виноват, исправил.

Comment: Вам именно 4 знака? Потому что на самом деле это число - 2.6568999999999998173905...

Comment: Там сколько ввёл, столько и должно показать.

Comment: @Ischariot "Там сколько ввёл, столько и должно показать." - проще всего такое реализовать если как строку вводить.

Comment: Тогда возвращаемся к строке. Потому что если вы сохраните это число в переменной типа `float` или `double` - то там вы никак не получите ровно 4 знака...

Comment: @Harry, смотря какая локаль, может быть и запятая.

Comment: @eanmos Я говорил о *коде*. В постановке вопроса ничего не было о том, как вводится это число...

Comment: @Harry, даже если и так. В русскоязычной литературе, вроде, принята плавающая *запятая*, а не точка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если для C, то можно примерно так:

```cpp
char buffer[256];
int i = 0;

// вводим число сразу в символьную строку
scanf("%s", buffer);


// пропускаем все символы до точки
while(buffer[i] != '.') 
{
    i++;
}

// выводим по смещению от точки
printf("%s", buffer + i + 1);
```

Вывод:

```
545123
```

P.S. по хорошему надо еще обработать ситуацию, когда число не содержит точку (например, было введено целое число).

Comment: Ваш вариант рабочий, но мне нужно, что бы я ввёл число не в самом коде, а в окне.
Работаю в CBlock.
Я только учусь на программиста, поэтому простите, если не так поставил вопрос или чего то не понимаю.

Comment: ну тогда ничего конвертировать не нужно, можно просто вместо функции `sprintf` сделать `scanf("%s", buffer)`

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает.

Comment: Но если ввести авторское 2.6569 - то вы получите 656900. Так сказать, ой...

Comment: @Harry Ничего подобного, при вводе 2.6569 на выходе будет 6569. То что мне и нужно было.

Comment: Напишите тогда разработчикам МС++, а заодно и GCC, что они ничего не понимают... Потому что вот: https://ideone.com/6A29z9 *Ничего подобного*?... :)

Comment: @Harry Вы внимательно читайте, там вместо `sprintf` `scanf("%s", buffer)`  и тогда при вводе числа будет именно 6569.

Comment: В ответе этого нет. Вряд ли другие заинтересованные в ответе люди будут внимательно перечитывать все комментарии - типа, вдруг ответ неверный :)

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял что вам нужно, то вот пример:

```
double num;
cin >> num;
//Избавляемся от целой части
double s = num - (int)num;
//Точность (цифр после точки)
int accuracy = 1e4;
//Результат
int res = s * accuracy;
cout << res << endl;
```

Но хочу заметить, что если вы введете `2.6569`, то будет выведено `6568` т.к. в памяти число хранится `656899999992`.

Можно рассчитывать результат таким образом:

```
int res = floor(s * accuracy + .5);
```